# why do parenthesis around braces enable preprocessor macro return values

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

When I write a macro I like to enclose the definition in braces (i.e., `{` `}`) to prevent any potiential namespace clashes that may occur. However, in order to get a return value from the macro, the macro definition for some reason also needs to be wrapped in parenthesis. Omitting the surrounding parenthesis causes no value to be returned. Why is that?

For example

```c
#define ADD1(x)    \
  ({int y = (x) + 1; \
    y;})

int foo = 3;
int bar = ADD1(foo);
//
// versus
//
#define ADD1_BROKEN(x) \
  {int y = (x) + 1;    \
   y;}

int baz = ADD_BROKEN(foo); // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with preprocessor. Try gcc -E on your code

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to use a regular function instead?

Comment: is it c or c++ please don't put both tags

Comment: @Bob__ its just for my own understanding. Admittedly the example is contrived. I don't think most people would want/need a function or macro that adds 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have in your first macro is a [*expression statement*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) which is a gcc extension.  It allows for a block statement in a place where an expression is allowed, with the last statement in the block being the value of the expression.

The second case doesn't work because you're attempting to use a block statement as an expression which isn't allowed.

That being said, your particular example would work better as a simple expression:

```
#define ADD1(x) ((x) + 1)
```

If you really need something complex that looks like a function, just make a function.

Comment: The code was just a contrived macro to illustrate what I am talking about. But you are correct it is indeed a gcc extension (but clang also seems to support it). Can be verified at the commandline by adding `-pedantic` flag to gcc/clang. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessor macros are a text replacement - nothing more, nothing less.  After preprocessing, the line

```
int bar = ADD1(foo);
```

*expands* into

```
int bar = ({int y = (x) + 1; y;});
```

which is an expression statement; this is an extension offered by compilers like `gcc` - I don't think this would compile with `-pedantic`.

The broken version expands into

```
int baz = {int y = (x) + 1; y;};
```

which is invalid declaration syntax.